# golang passing func as param to another func

Tags: go, parameters, func

Main question is "is it possible to pass any type func as param and how?".
I am learning Go and want to make my own async wrap function like this:

```
func AsyncFunc(fn func(), args ...interface{}) chan bool {
    var done chan bool;

    go func() {
        fn(args...);
        done <- true;
    }();

    return done;
}
```

and call it:

```
max := func(a, b int) int {
    //some hard code what will be goroutine
    if a > b {return a};
    return b;
}

done := AsyncFunc(max, 5, 8);
//some pretty code
<- done;
```

P.S. sorry for my English if it is bad...

Edit1:
I know it is useless, slow and danger. It is just my crazy idea what i want just realise.

Comment: The exact signature of the function must be known compile time.

Comment: Why do you want to do it the hard way? Just launch the goroutine in the place where you would use your `AsyncFunc()` and be done with it without any unnessesary complexity...

Comment: Because I want do it for myself. I'm not satisfied if i can't make smth if it possible. Also I like hard way, it helps me to learn new :)

Comment: @kerrytazi Change signature to `AsyncFunc(fn func(a, b int) int, args ...interface{})` Try it. BTW why are you using `;` on every line? Also I recommend you to pass `done chan` as a parameter to the `AsyncFunc` instead of creating a channel on every call.

Comment: If you want it totally generic, you would have to pass the func in as an `interface{}` and call it using reflection.

Comment: @jeevatkm I want use it more then one time, that's why i creating new channels. Also i want use it with any type funcs with any count of arguments, not only `func(a, b int) int` like, for example `func(a string) string`, that's why i dont want use signatures.
P.S. using `;` is not bad, it's just my habit from another langs.

Comment: @kerrytazi Let's go one by one. 1) You can use it more than once. 2) if you want `n` of arguments, you have to use `interface{}`, `Variadic` funcs and type assertion 3) I believe we have to value the language syntax instead of habit 4) I have created the sample code https://play.golang.org/p/Lf7jZpwAl9 pls have a look

Comment: @Adrian, can u explain it or give some usefull link with info?

Comment: Look at the documentation for the [`reflect`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/) package. I have to say though, I strongly recommend against it, as you lose all compile-time checking of the function calls, opening yourself up to all sorts of silly runtime errors. I'm with @ain, **don't use a function for this, just do it inline**.

Comment: @jeevatkm, i mean smth like this https://play.golang.org/p/3IwDOb4TfC

Comment: @kerrytazi It is doable and manageable in the codebase, if you have fixed set of function signatures that will be passed to `AsyncFunc` and handling via func assertion. If answer yes then let me know, I will draft the answer based on comments conversation. However I'm not sure what is your goal is?

Comment: @Adrian thank you for your answer, i learn more about go and now understand u
[the final version](https://play.golang.org/p/0MGZ6MxkK1)

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/12655464/12817546.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i found the way to do what i want.

```
 package main


 import (
     "fmt"
 )


 func t1(t int) {
     fmt.Printf("%d\n", t);
 }


 func t2(t string) {
     fmt.Printf("%s\n", t);
 }


 func test(fn interface{}, data interface{}) {
     switch fn.(type) {
     case func(string):
         fn.(func(string))(data.(string))
     case func(int):
         fn.(func(int))(data.(int))
     }
 }


 func main() {
     test(t1, 123);
     test(t2, "test");
 }
```

Comment: Isn't this a very poor way for doing what you originally set out to do. I thought your main objective was to find a way to implement "AsyncFunc" that could accept any generic function. Your solution only accepts int and string type and would become a no-op for all other types.

Answer (score 6):

Of course Go can do it. Please consider the following simple example:

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
)

type funcDef func(string) string

func foo(s string) string {
        return fmt.Sprintf("from foo: %s", s)
}

func test(someFunc funcDef, s string) string {
        return someFunc(s)
}

func main() {
        output := test(foo, "some string")
        fmt.Println(output)
}
```

And to be specific in your case, you just need to:

```
type funcDef func(int, int) int

func AsyncFunc(func funcDef, a, b int) chan bool {
    ....
}

done := AsyncFunc(max, 5, 8)
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all.

Comment: @Adrian Edited, that should directly answered the question this time, :)