# Pass a function as a parameter in go function

Tags: function, go

I want to pass a function as a parameter in a go function. Here is my code:

```
func Call(path string, method func()) {
    // TODO launch the method here
}
```

When I want to call this function, I want to do this:

```
func routes() {
    app.Call("/", controllers.Index())
}
```

And the `Index()` method is:

```
func Index(res http.ResponseWriter, req http.Request) {
    userAgent := req.Header.Get("User-Agent")
    fmt.Fprintf(res, "You're User-Agent is %s", userAgent)
}
```

Is a good idea to create a `type` and pass this `type` as parameter ?

Comment: You don't need it, as in _go_ you can pass the function directly. Have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12655464/can-functions-be-passed-as-parameters-in-go)

Comment: You can refer to this answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12655719/5692089

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's entirely up to you if you create a named type. Technically you are defining a type even if you do it anonymously in the signature (the type is `func()` in your code). Whether or not it needs to be defined with a name is up to you and depends on your use case and needs.

Whether or not you define a named type, the function signatures must match (you can't pass a `func(http.ResponseWriter, http.Request)` to a `func()` argument), and you have to pass the function rather than calling it and passing its return value (which it does not have):

```
// Correct arguments required
func Call(path string, method func(http.ResponseWriter, http.Request)) {
    // TODO launch the method here
}

func routes() {
     // Index() calls the function, you just want to pass a reference to it
    app.Call("/", controllers.Index)
}
```